# Adicionar imagem ao .jar

Tags: java, eclipse

Eu tenho vários programas que rodam perfeitamente na minha máquina, o `.jar` roda tranquilamente e eu os utilizo como bem desejo, sem problemas. No entanto, quando vou executá-los em outra máquina, as imagens não aparecem. O programa roda perfeitamente, tudo da forma como deve ser, mas as imagens simplesmente não aparecem.

Aqui vai um dos programas que mais gostaria que rodasse, uma calculadora. Eu alterei o ícone do `JOpTionPane.showMessageDialog`, que está no menu, e o ícone não aparece.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculadora extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JButton n1;
private JButton n2;
private JButton n3;
private JButton n4;
private JButton n5;
private JButton n6;
private JButton n7;
private JButton n8;
private JButton n9;
private JButton n0;
private JButton botaoMais;
private JButton botaoMenos;
private JButton botaoVezes;
private JButton botaoDividi;
private JButton botaoIgual;
private JButton botaoC;
private JButton botaoCE;
private JButton botaoPonto;
private char operacao;
private int inteiro;
private int decimal;
private double memoria;
private boolean ponto;
private JLabel creditos;
private JTextField campo;

public Calculadora(){
    setTitle("Calculadora do Ozzy");
    setBounds(0,0,280,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(190,194,233));
    setLayout(null);

    JMenuBar mBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu opcoes = new JMenu("Opções");
    JMenuItem sobreCalc = new JMenuItem("Sobre");
    JMenuItem sobreMim = new JMenuItem("Sobre mim");

    opcoes.add(sobreCalc);
    opcoes.add(sobreMim);

    JMenu sair = new JMenu("Sair");
    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem ("Sair");

    sair.add(exit);

    mBar.add(opcoes);
    mBar.add(sair);
    setJMenuBar(mBar);

    inteiro = 0;
    decimal = 0;
    memoria = 0;

    n1 = new JButton ();
    n1.setText("1");
    n1.setBounds(25,115,45,45);
    n1.setBackground(new Color(134,142,215));
    n1.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add(n1);

    n2 = new JButton ();
    n2.setText("2");
    n2.setBounds(85,115,45,45);
    n2.setBackground(new Color(134,142,215));
    n2.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add(n2);

    n3 = new JButton();
    n3.setText("3");
    n3.setBounds(140,115,45,45);
    n3.setBackground(new Color(134,142,215));
    n3.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add(n3);

    n4 = new JButton();
    n4.setText ("4");
    n4.setBounds (25,170,45,45);
    n4.setBackground(new Color(134,142,215));
    n4.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add(n4);

    n5 = new JButton ();
    n5.setText("5");
    n5.setBounds(85,170,45,45);
    n5.setBackground(new Color(134,142,215));
    n5.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add (n5);

    n6 = new JButton();
    n6.setText("6");
    n6.setBounds(140,170,45,45);
    n6.setBackground(new Color(134,142,215));
    n6.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add(n6);

    n7 = new JButton ();
    n7.setText("7");
    n7.setBounds(25,225,45,45);
    n7.setBackground(new Color(134,142,215));
    n7.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add(n7);

    n8 = new JButton();
    n8.setText("8");
    n8.setBounds (85,225,45,45);
    n8.setBackground(new Color(134,142,215));
    n8.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add (n8);

    n9 = new JButton ();
    n9.setText("9");
    n9.setBounds (140,225,45,45);
    n9.setBackground(new Color(134,142,215));
    n9.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add (n9);

    n0 = new JButton();
    n0.setText ("0");
    n0.setBounds (140,280,45,45);
    n0.setBackground(new Color(134,142,215));
    n0.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add (n0);

    botaoMais = new JButton();
    botaoMais.setText("+");
    botaoMais.setBounds(195,115,45,45);
    botaoMais.setBackground(new Color(133,197,235));
    botaoMais.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add(botaoMais);

    botaoMenos = new JButton ();
    botaoMenos.setText ("-");
    botaoMenos.setBounds(195,170,45,45);
    botaoMenos.setBackground(new Color(133,197,235));
    botaoMenos.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add (botaoMenos);

    botaoVezes = new JButton();
    botaoVezes.setText ("x");
    botaoVezes.setBounds(195,225,45,45);
    botaoVezes.setBackground(new Color(133,197,235));
    botaoVezes.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add(botaoVezes);

    botaoDividi = new JButton();
    botaoDividi.setText("÷");
    botaoDividi.setBounds(195,280,45,45);
    botaoDividi.setBackground(new Color(133,197,235));
    botaoDividi.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add(botaoDividi);

    botaoIgual = new JButton();
    botaoIgual.setText("=");
    botaoIgual.setBounds(25,280,45,45);
    botaoIgual.setBackground(new Color(133,197,235));
    botaoIgual.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add(botaoIgual);

    botaoPonto = new JButton ();
    botaoPonto.setText(".");
    botaoPonto.setBounds(85,280,45,45);
    botaoPonto.setBackground(new Color(133,197,235));
    botaoPonto.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add (botaoPonto);

    botaoC = new JButton ();
    botaoC.setText("C");
    botaoC.setBounds(25,65,105,40);
    botaoC.setBackground(new Color (157,182,210));
    botaoC.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add(botaoC);

    botaoCE = new JButton ();
    botaoCE.setText("CE");
    botaoCE.setBounds(140,65,100,40);
    botaoCE.setBackground(new Color(157,182,210));
    botaoCE.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add(botaoCE);

    campo = new JTextField();
    campo.setBounds(25,25,216,30);
    this.add(campo);

    creditos = new JLabel();
    creditos.setBounds(78,287,200,100);
    creditos.setText("Gabriel Ozzy Santos");
    this.add(creditos);

    n1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            if(ponto){
                decimal +=1;
            } else{
            inteiro *= 10;
            inteiro +=1;

            }
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+ "1");
        }
    });
    n2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            if (ponto){
                decimal +=2;
            }else{
            inteiro *=10;
            inteiro+= 2;

            }
            campo.setText (campo.getText()+"2");
        }
    });
    n3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            if (ponto){
                decimal+=3;
            }else {
            inteiro *= 10;
            inteiro += 3;
            }
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+"3");

        }
    });
    n4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            if (ponto){
                decimal+=4;
            }else {
            inteiro *= 10;
            inteiro +=4;
            }
            campo.setText (campo.getText ()+"4");

        }
    });
    n5.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
            if (ponto){
                decimal +=5;
            }else{
            inteiro*= 10;
            inteiro +=5;
            }
            campo.setText (campo.getText ()+ "5");
        }
    });
    n6.addActionListener (new ActionListener (){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
            if (ponto){
                decimal +=6;
            }else {
            inteiro*= 10;
            inteiro +=6;
            }
            campo.setText (campo.getText ()+ "6");
        }
    });
    n7.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
            if(ponto){
                decimal +=7;
            }else {
            inteiro*= 10;
            inteiro +=7;
            }
            campo.setText (campo.getText()+"7");
        }
    });
    n8.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            if(ponto){
                decimal +=8;
            }else{
            inteiro *=10;
            inteiro +=8;
            }
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+"8");
        }
    });
    n9.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            if (ponto){
                decimal +=9;
            }else{
            inteiro *=10;
            inteiro +=9;
            }
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+"9");

        }
    });
    n0.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            if(ponto){
                decimal +=0;
            }else{
            inteiro*=10;
            inteiro +=0;
            }
            campo.setText(campo.getText()+"0");
        }
    });
    botaoMais.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            double numero =Double.parseDouble(String.format("%s.%s",inteiro,decimal));

            String t1 = campo.getText();
            if(!"".equals(t1))
            numero = Double.parseDouble(t1);

            operacao = '+';
            if (memoria > 0){
                memoria += numero;
            }else{
                    memoria = numero;
                }
            inteiro = 0;
            numero = 0;
            decimal = 0;
            ponto = false;
            campo.setText("");
            }
        });
    botaoMenos.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            double numero = Double.parseDouble (String.format("%s.%s",inteiro,decimal));

            String t1 = campo.getText();
            if(!"".equals(t1))
            numero = Double.parseDouble(t1);

            operacao = '-';
            if (memoria > 0){
                memoria -= numero;
            }else {
                memoria = numero;
            }
            numero = 0;
            inteiro = 0;
            decimal = 0;
            ponto = false;
            campo.setText("");
        }
    });
    botaoVezes.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            double numero = Double.parseDouble (String.format("%s.%s",inteiro,decimal));

            String t1 = campo.getText();
            if(!"".equals(t1))
            numero = Double.parseDouble(t1);

            operacao = '*';
            if (memoria > 0){
                memoria *= numero;
            }else {
                memoria = numero;
            }
            numero = 0;
            inteiro =0;
            decimal =0;
            ponto = false;      
            campo.setText("");
        }
    });
    botaoDividi.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
            double numero = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%s.%s",inteiro,decimal));

            String t1 = campo.getText();
            if(!"".equals(t1))
            numero = Double.parseDouble(t1);

            operacao = '/';
            if(memoria > 0){
                memoria /=numero;
            }else {
                memoria = numero;
            }
            numero=0;
            inteiro =0;
            decimal = 0;
            ponto = false;
            campo.setText("");
        }
    });
    botaoC.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
            inteiro = 0;
            decimal = 0;
            memoria = 0;
            ponto = false;
            campo.setText("");
        }
    });
    botaoCE.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
            inteiro = 0;
            decimal = 0;
            ponto = false;
            campo.setText("");
        }
    });
    botaoPonto.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
            if (!ponto){
                campo.setText(inteiro +".");
                ponto = (true);
            }
        }
    });
    botaoIgual.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            double numero = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%s.%s", inteiro, decimal));

            String t1 = campo.getText();
            if(!"".equals(t1))
            numero = Double.parseDouble(t1);

            switch (operacao){
            case '+':{
                memoria += numero;
                break;
            }
            case '-':{
                memoria -=numero;
                break;
            }
            case '*':{
                memoria *=numero;
                break;
            }
            case '/':{
                memoria /=numero;
                break;
            }
            }
            numero = 0;
            campo.setText(""+ memoria);
        }
    });

    sobreCalc.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            Icon about = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Gabriel Ozzy/Downloads/Java2.jpg");  
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Programado em Java 7 - Plataforma Eclipse", "Sobre o software",0,about);
        }
    });
    sobreMim.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            Icon about2 = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Gabriel Ozzy/Downloads/Java2.jpg");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Programador: Gabriel Ozzy Santos","Sobre o desenvolvedor",0,about2);
        }
    });
    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
}

public static void main (String [] args){
    Calculadora cCalculadora = new Calculadora();
        cCalculadora.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Aqui está o erro: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu sempre coloco todas as imagens que eu vou usar dentro de um novo pacote, assim quando eu gerar um .jar não preciso me preocupar com elas, pois vão estar lá dentro.

Criei um novo pacote chamado assets, e dentro dele coloquei as imagens que eu preciso e em outro pacote criei uma classe para efetuar o teste de load da imagem.
Conforme a estrutura a seguir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como ficou a classe que carrega as imagens e fiz um teste se a imagem foi carregada com sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode usar várias formas para carregar a imagem, usei uma simples conforme a necessidade.
E a saída do console indicando que a imagem foi carregada com sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta ! Poderia me explicar com mais precisão para que serve o MediaTracker ? obrigado !

Comment: MediaTracker é uma classe utilitária para acompanhar o status de objetos de mídia. Usei um atributo da classe que retorna um valor inteiro, cujo significado é se um objeto de mídia foi carregado com sucesso e comparei com o retorno do método getImageLoadStatus(). Esse método pedia para mim olhar os atributos referente ao carregamento de mídia da classe MediaTracker, então depois de olhar fiz a comparação. Recomendo ler a documentação da classe em http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente aqui, depois de dois dias inteiros louco atrás disso ! Hahaha, obrigado !

Comment: Por nada, fico feliz que tenha funcionado.

Answer (score 2):

Crie um arquivo .zip com todas suas imagens e adicione no seu Build Path.

> Botão direito na pasta do seu projeto > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add JARs

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para usar a imagem no seu código, por exemplo faça:

```
JLabel lblImg1 = new JLabel("");
JLabel lblImg2 = new JLabel("");
lblImg1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Principal.class.getResource("/img1.png"))); 
lblImg2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Principal.class.getResource("/img2.png")));
```

Use o nome das imagens que se encontram dentro do seu zip.

Na hora de exportar o jar ele incluirá automaticamente o seu arquivo .zip que contém as imagens.

Comment: Fiz isso e o Eclipse deu o "compute launch error" só resolveu depois de eu ter removido... alguma outra maneira ?

Comment: @GabrielOzzy foi um erro de compilação ou foi uma exceção lançada durante a execução? poderia adicionar o stacktrace() ou uma imagem do erro?

Comment: No mesmo instante que eu terminei de adicionar o .zip, apareceu esse erro e o Eclipse simplesmente nao respondia a execução de nenhum outro programa... A imagem está na pergunta, que acabei de editar!

Comment: @GabrielOzzy você chegou a reiniciar o Eclipse e tentar novamente? Não tenho certeza que o erro foi causado por adicionar o arquivo .zip no build path. Quais tipos de imagens você está usando? Se for jpeg conforme seu código não é para dar problema.

Comment: Reiniciei, mas não deu jeito... os tipos de imagens são JPG mesmo, também não estou entendendo a razão do problema...

Comment: @GabrielOzzy o erro persiste? Andei pesquisando sobre esse erro e me parece ser um bug do eclipse, entretanto não sei como ele é causado nem como consertar. Só me explica uma coisa, quando você adicionar o zip ele passa a dar esse erro e quando você remove ele volta a funcionar, é isso? Não sei se resolve e não acho que seja um bom conselho, mas se quiser arriscar tenta atualizar seu Eclipse para a última versão.

Comment: Infelizmente eu já utilizo a última versão... Vou tentar encontrar outra maneira, obrigado amigo !

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sei se já foi resolvido, mas vou responder. Quando vou utilizar imagens em meus projetos eu crio uma pasta dentro da pasta do projeto e faço assim:

```
Icon about = new ImageIcon("minhaPasta/Java2.jpg");
```

E quando vou utilizar em outra máquina eu copio o jar e esta pasta. Sempre funciona.

Comment: boa resposta, apenas deixe um pouco mais claro como deve ficar a estrutura das pastas, tipo, seu jar e pasta das imagens devem estar no mesmo nível, correto? se desejar editar sua resposta e eu apago meu comentário daí

Comment: Ainda não foi resolvido... mas ai então, no caso, você teria sempre que copiar o .jar e a pasta juntos, é isso ? É que isso seria complicado... deve ter uma outra maneira, acredito...