# Imagem não aparece depois que gero o .jar

Tags: java, javafx

Como faço pra minha imagem aparecer na aplicação após a geração do .jar? Estou fazendo da seguinte forma e não está dando certo.

```
@FXML
private ImageView image;
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    File file = new File("src/icons/logo-superplano.png");
     Image imagem = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
     image.setImage(imagem);
}
```

Comment: Olha essa questão. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15574/adicionar-imagem-ao-jar/15719#15719

Comment: A imagem já está dentro de um pacote. E quando eu uso
`Image image2 = new Image(frmLoginController.class.getResourceAsStream("/src/icons/logo-superplano.png"));` da erro.

Comment: Posta o erro ai.

Comment: `Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Comment: Quando você tenta da maneira que está na pergunta, ocorre o mesmo erro?

Comment: Não, a imagem aparece quando compilo e rodo o programa. Porém quando gero o .jar a imagem não aparece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema colocando a imagem no mesmo pacote da classe principal. E depois usei esse código:

```
Image imagem = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("logo-superplano.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Abri o jar com winrar e copia arquivo ou pasta e só arrastar o arquivo ou pasta para o winrar

Comment: Não entendi....

Comment: abri o .jar  com o winrar e depois arrasta os arquivos ou pasta para dentro do winrar que ele copia os arquivos ou pasta para dentro do .jar

Comment: Arrastar quais pastas para dentro do winrar? Pois minha imagem já está dentro do pacote.

Comment: A pasta icons.O compilador só coloca arquivos sources dentro de um jar e não imagens você tem que copia manualmente as imagens

Comment: A pasta icons ja esta dentro do jar. Quando abro pelo winrar já está la.

Comment: Com as imagens?

Comment: Como disse eu coloquei a imagem dentro de um pacote com o nome icons. Acredito que quando eu crio um pacote ele já fica dentro do src

Comment: Sim, com a imagem

Comment: Tenta isto `File file = new File("classpath:icons/logo-superplano.png");`

Comment: Não aparece a imagem